# How to append selected columns to pandas dataframe from df with different columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to be able to append df1 df2, df3 into one df_All , but since each of the dataframe has different column. How could I do this in for loop ( I have others stuff that i have to do in the for loop )  ?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('A', [1, 2, 3]), ('B', [4, 5, 6])])
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('B', [5, 6, 7]), ('A', [8, 9, 10])])
df3 = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('C', [5, 6, 7]), ('D', [8, 9, 10]), ('A',[1,2,3]), ('B',[4,5,7])])
list = ['df1','df2','df3']
df_All = pd.DataFrame()
for i in list:
   # doing something else as well --- 
    df_All = df_All.append(i)
```

[image]

I want my df_All to only have ( A & B ) only, is there a way to this in loop above ? something like append only this two columns ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If I understand what you want then you need to select just columns 'A' and 'B' from `df3` and then use [`pd.concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat) :

```
In [35]:

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('A', [1, 2, 3]), ('B', [4, 5, 6])])
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('B', [5, 6, 7]), ('A', [8, 9, 10])])
df3 = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('C', [5, 6, 7]), ('D', [8, 9, 10]), ('A',[1,2,3]), ('B',[4,5,7])])
df_list = [df1,df2,df3[['A','B']]]
pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
Out[35]:
    A  B
0   1  4
1   2  5
2   3  6
3   8  5
4   9  6
5  10  7
6   1  4
7   2  5
8   3  7
```

Note that in your original code this is poor practice:

```
list = ['df1','df2','df3']
```

This shadows the built in type `list` plus even if it was actually a valid var name like `df_list` you've created a list of strings and not a list of dfs.

If you want to determine the common columns then you can determine this using the `np.intersection` method on the columns:

```
In [39]:

common_cols = df1.columns.intersection(df2.columns).intersection(df3.columns)
common_cols
Out[39]:
Index(['A', 'B'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: I am trying to do this is in for loop since the actual code have varies df .. sometimes ( df1, df2 ) sometimes ( df1, df2, df3 )  and also other calculation that i have to do in the loop.  Do you know if there a way to do this ?

Comment: You're going to have to flesh your question out significantly as it's unclear to me, there is no reason I see why you can't even after performing some operations on the dfs concatenate them all at the end

Comment: oh, sorry I was not clear.. so basically the reason that I have to have it in the loop ( list ) because sometimes if I run the code there will be 100 dataframes that need to be combined . sometimes will be 500 dataframes all together. so the number of dataframes is different each time I ran the code. so I can not pan out how many dataframe i need each time, it must come from the "list"  - let me know if this makes sense...

Answer (score 5):

You can also use set comprehension to join all common columns from an arbitrary list of DataFrames:

```
df_list = [df1, df2, df3]
common_cols = list(set.intersection(*(set(c) for c in df_list)))
df_new = pd.concat([df[common_cols] for df in df_list], ignore_index=True)
>>> df_new 
    A  B
0   1  4
1   2  5
2   3  6
3   8  5
4   9  6
5  10  7
6   1  4
7   2  5
8   3  7
```