# Append a small dataframe to the bottom of a large Dataframe on specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, concatenation

I have a small dataframe with two columns, which have to be appended to the bottom of a large dataframe. The two columns of the smaller dataframe exist on the larger dataframe as well but as a sub-header. how to do I append the small dataframe at the bottom of the larger dataframe.

PS: I'm not a pro at python, so if there is a better approach to do the same, I'm open to that as well.

EDIT: The large df has multi-indexed columns

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to append selected columns to pandas dataframe from df with different columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29335857/how-to-append-selected-columns-to-pandas-dataframe-from-df-with-different-column)

Comment: My large dataframe is multi-indexed, will it work on that as well?

Comment: can you share any data sample and you desired output, so, it would be easy to provide the possible solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the link you shared sort off help. Although my approach had completely changed by that time.